# Addition of two angular momenta

Tags: quantum-mechanics, angular-momentum, quantum-spin

In addition of angular momenta, does both the relations depict the same thing?

$$
\vec{J} = (\vec{J_1}\otimes 1 +1\otimes \vec{J_2})
$$

$$
\vec{J} = (\vec{J_2}\otimes 1 +1\otimes \vec{J_1})
$$

Answer (score 2):

In essence yes, the only difference is in the labels you give to each subspace - 1 or 2.

This could mean simply giving different labels to particle 1 and particle 2, each of which has certain angular momentum. Or if the system is one particle with orbital and spin contributions to its angular momentum its just a different assignation of labels one and two to each part. The tensor product and its decomposition goes through the same since it is symmetric in subspaces 1 and 2.

Answer (score 1):

Physically yes but technically the order matters in the sense that the phase of the state of "good" $J$ actually depend on the ordering.  Writing
\begin{align}
\vert J M_J\rangle =\sum_{m_1m_2} C_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2}^{JM_J}\vert j_1m_1\rangle 
\vert j_2m_2\rangle 
\end{align}
where $C_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2}^{JM_J}$ is a [Clebsch-Gordan coefficient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clebsch%E2%80%93Gordan_coefficients), and using
the symmetry property
\begin{align}
C_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2}^{JM_J}=(-1)^{j_1+j_2-J}C_{j_2m_2;j_1m_1}^{JM_J}
\end{align}
shows that inverting the role of $j_1$ and $j_2$ may introduce an overall phase 
$(-1)^{j_1+j_2-J}$ in the construction of $\vert JM_J\rangle$, i.e.
\begin{align}
\vert J M_J\rangle =\sum_{m_1m_2} C_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2}^{JM_J}\vert j_1m_1\rangle 
\vert j_2m_2\rangle = (-1)^{j_1+j_2-J}\sum_{m_1m_2} C_{j_1m_1;j_2m_2}^{JM_J}\vert j_2m_2\rangle\vert j_1m_1\rangle 
\end{align}